# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. Is possible another script or command to get database from csv format for data analysis through jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, parsing, jupyter-notebook

I tried to import a database from csv format unsuccessfully, by using the script bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('banco_aglomerado.csv')
```

However, I got this message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-5082ff70590d> in <module>
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv('banco_aglomerado.csv')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    452 
    453     try:
--> 454         data = parser.read(nrows)
    455     finally:
    456         parser.close()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1131     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1132         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1133         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1134 
   1135         # May alter columns / col_dict

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2035     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2036         try:
-> 2037             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2038         except StopIteration:
   2039             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 133, saw 3
```

So I looked to some alternative ways given before by this forum community, but doesn't work...If anyone here knows another possible way to solve this problem, please help me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. I have two small suggestions for your future questions. First, the last line of the error message says that the problem is in line 133 of the input file. Looking at that line would probably have helped you understand your problem, and it would certainly have been helpful to include that line in your question (and possibly a bit of the beginning of the input file). The more details you provide, the easier it is to answer. Second, it's worth spending a little bit of time with the docs for a package before you give up and start looking for a different package.

Answer (score 0):

This precise problem is shown in the [pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-bad-lines). (The example even shows a backtrace remarkably similar to the one which you show.)

In summary, the CSV reader has decided that the data frame contains only two columns, probably because the first line had two columns. At line 133 of the input, it encounters a line with three data fields. By default, this line is considered bad input, and parsing stops.

Since pandas wants to create a rectangular array, it can only handle CSV files which produce the same number of fields on each row. However, you have a couple of options about how to do this.

The most obvious solution is to fix your input data so that it has the expected number of fields on each line. If the extra field indicates a real problem in your input data, that's definitely the way to go. To do this, you could add `error_bad_lines=False` to your `read_csv` call, which will allow the read to continue, producing a warning for each bad line.

You could use the same procedure to just drop lines with an incorrect field count. I don't think this is a great idea in most cases, but it might be appropriate in some cases.

If you feel that it is sufficient to drop the extra fields from lines with too many fields, you can do that with the `usecols` parameter. To do this, you have to know how many fields you expect. If you are expecting two fields per row, you can use `usecols=[1,2]` to specify that the first and second field should be used and extra fields, if any, should be dropped.

Read the documentation linked above for more details, and consult the [reference manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for a complete list of `read_csv` options.